# PHP Dom XML Parsing on empty self closing tags

Tags: php, xml, dom, tags

I'm using DOM to parse an xml file.
And I am having trouble catching an error that throws when the XML tag is empty and self closed.

eg. 
   `<Title />`

```
$xml=("http://www.example.com/xml-to-parse.xml");
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

$element = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('Root');

for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    $id = $element->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('Title')
                  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

The error I am getting is:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty tag is not going to have any child nodes, thus the second item(0) in your last line is not going to return a valid object, and so attempting to get its value via nodeValue is going to throw the error you're getting because it doesn't have a proper object to work on.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much.
My main problem is finding a way to check if the the tag has any child Nodes.
I've tried "item(0)->hasChildNodes" but have had no luck.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Could you add the code that you were trying with hasChildNodes?

Comment: Nevermind I have resolved it now. I removed the "childNodes->item(0)->" and it works fine. 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The XML error you're receiving isn't due to the tag being self-closing; that's valid XML. It's likely due to not finding a tag named Title, or there not being 10 of them returned (which is a bad way to write it anyway, better to base the loop off of $x->length, which is a known value).

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion.
I have changed it to X->length but the error is still there.
My problem is there are 10 different $x items to loop through and only one of them is empty with the self closing tag. I need a way of checking if the tag is empty. 
Would you be able to help at all?

Comment: The hasAttributes() function will tell you if it's an empty (self-closing) tag: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/domnode.hasattributes.php

Comment: Correction: my above comment won't tell you if it's an *empty* tag -- it could still contain other tags, it will just tell you if it has attributes. hasChildNodes() will tell you if it has children. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/domnode.haschildnodes.php